# Update off Windows 10, But Auto start again

Tags: windows, windows-10

My windows 10 updated was off. But some day's later, It automatically taken update.I also remove from service.It's happens several times.How can I off permanently updated from my pc.

Comment: I already done this way.But I did not get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

> - Press the Windows logo key + R then type gpedit.msc and click OK.
> - Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update.
> - Double-click Configure Automatic Updates.
> - Select Disabled in Configured Automatic Updates on the left, and click Apply and OK to disable the Windows automatic update feature.

Answer (score 0):

1. we can try to run the following cmd as an administrator to disable automatically update and restart the computer:

**Sc.exe stop wuauserv**

**Sc.exe config wuauserv start= disabled**

**schtasks /Change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\sih" /Disable**

**schtasks /Change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\sihboot" /Disable**

**schtasks /Change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\Scheduled Start" /Disable**

**schtasks /Change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\Automatic App Update" /Disable**

2. Try the following gpo:
   Administrative Templates | System | Internet Communication Management | Internet Communication Settings|Turn off access to all Windows Update features
3. Windows Update won`t be downloaded from a metered network. We could configure the network as "metered" network as a workaround to disable updates.

Best regards,